# regex validation for alphanumeric and smaller character

Tags: regex, validation

I need to use `<` character in a regular expression,

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9>_/.\<-]*$"
```

This pattern is supposed to match alphanumeric characters and  `> _ / . -`

However, I cannot use `<` character in it.

I tried `\<` but it did not work.

Comment: "i need to use < character in regex" - why? what are you trying to do ? try focusing your question on what you're trying to achieve - not on "how" you're trying to do it

Comment: Is it inside some XML? Try `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` then. Or better put your regex into a CData block.

Comment: i use in jsf rich validation like below, i wanna add "<" character too

<f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9>_/.-]*$"/>

Comment: If XML, running it through a parser is a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an XML attribute, you need to use XML entities for < and >.

This is a variant with just a lessthan sign

```
 <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9&lt;_/.-]*$"/>
```

This will match both greaterthan and lessthan signs

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9&gt;&lt;_/.-]*$"/>
```

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, if you plan to use apostrophe or ampersand, do not forget to xmlize them, too.